# Putting complex formula to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put a formula to a cell and the values that I will be using is based on another cell(not a fix cell). 
This is the formula if it is on the excel's formula bar.

```
=IF(AND(D9=0,J9<>0),100%,IFERROR(K9/D9,0))
```

But I cannot  use this in vba because the formula should be flexible in every cell that I will be using this. Here's my code(I know its not good.)

```
ws.Range("L" & src1).Formula = "=IF(AND(" & ws.Range("D" & src1).Value & "=0," & ws.Range("J" & src1).Value & "<>0),100%,IFERROR(" & ws.Range("K" & src1).Value / ws.Range("D" & src1).Value & ",0))"
```

Comment: If you're putting ***values*** in the formula, why don't just calculate the result?

Comment: I think its more hassle if I'm going to calculate it one by one because this formula is inside a loop.

Comment: I don't see how that's better than filling cells with stuff like `=IF(AND(10=0,42<>0),100%,IFERROR(66/10,0))`

Comment: Ahhh okay I got your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming src1 is an integer value, I believe you want:

```
ws.Range("L" & src1).Formula = "=IF(AND(D" & src1 & "=0,J" & src1 & "<>0),100%,IFERROR(K" & src1 & "/D" & src1 & ",0))"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the output was not on percentage.

Comment: But your suggestion works. I think I just have to figure out something on this. THANKS a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by `was not on percentage`?  If you mean the cell wasn't formatted as a percentage, that just requires an extra line of code saying `ws.Range("L" & src1).Style = "Percent"`.

Comment: Also, wanna ask how to convert this one to a vba code?
`=IF(OR(K9<-5%,K9>5%),"Yes","No")`. I really had a hard time quoting and converting it that it ends up having an error

Comment: I tried this but it pop-out an error indicating "Application or Object defined error" `ws.Range("M" & src1).Formula = "=IF(OR(L" & src1 & "<-5%,L" & src1 & ">5%),""Yes"",""No""))"`

Comment: `=IF(OR(K9<-5%,K9>5%),"Yes","No")` would become `"=IF(OR(K" & src1 & "<-5%,K" & src1 & ">5%),""Yes"",""No"")"`, so you have an extra bracket at the end that you shouldn't have.  The easy way to do this is start with your original formula, change all quotation marks to be two quotation marks, change all row numbers (e.g. 9 in your formula) to be `" & src1 & "`, and add a quotation mark at the start and the end.